# Minimal Linux for virtual network lab

Tags: resources

I'm looking for a small linux (in memory and disk usage) distribution to be used in a network of virtual machines for lab testing.

Suggestions or pointers to related information?

**Addendum**

Now trying Alpine Linux ...

Comment: Some more specific requirements would be helpful, other than memory.

Comment: did you see http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Minimal_Linux_distros or https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/780781-6-excellent-lightweight-linux-distros-for-x86-and-arm ?

Comment: Very small distros include (not a full list), nanolinux (14 MB disk space), DSL (damn small linux, 50 MB) and puppy linux (100 MB, set for speed)

Answer (score 1):

Almost any distribution can be used as most can be installed with a minimum number of packages and active processes. Just run the installer from a distribution you are comfortable with and uncheck any package you do not actually need. If you really want to go minimal, download a distro installer from a couple of years ago, like a debian sarge or redhat 4 and use that. Since they are in a virtual (unconnected to the internet?) lab, vulnerabilities should not be a concern and sizes of 64-128MB RAM and disksizes < 1GB should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try Cirros , which is a minimal Linux distribution that was designed for use as a test image on clouds. 
https://launchpad.net/cirros